# Part selection for high-side switch

Tags: power, transistors, control

I plan to build 2 high-side switch, following this circuit :

[image]

The two switchs will be controlled by a ESP32 output : 3.3V, 40mA max.
The first one should power on/off a device with 5V / 500mA max
The second one should power on/off a device with 5V / 5A max

The first device is made of and I2C chip, some leds and some sensors.
The second device is made of 5 servo motors.

All the logic to control I2C, sensors, leds, motors is working fine.
Now I just want to switch power of these devices.

Since I'm aware of programming and "logical" components but a total newbie to all power management questions :

- could you tell me how to choose the right parts for R1/Q1 and R2/Q2, for each device ?
- What parameters should I compute ?
- Where do I found the relevant informations in the transistors/mosfets datasheets ?

Note : I know there's some decoupling/flyback diodes issues, this is not the point here.

Thanks.

Comment: *"help be to choose the right parts"*.  No.  We don't do that here.  Read the rules.

Comment: Question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chose a MOSFET that can carry the current you need at a low enough RDS_ON at your load current so it does not dissipate more heat than is acceptable to you.

Note: You need to use the \$I^2 * R_{DS_{ON}}\$ equation to calculate the power dissipated.

The MOSFET should also be capable of being switched as full to on as possible at 4.7V Vgs. That is Vgs MAX should be closer to +-5V not +-20V. Obviously it also need to hold off the supply voltage.

Once your MOSFET is selected figure out the wattage it will dissipate. From that you can decide if you need extra heat sinking, or a better part.

Q1 can be any general purpose NPN. R values look OK.

If this is for a battery operated project I'd increase both resistors by at least a factor of 10 if you do not need to run this at a high frequency. You may also want to consider using a small signal N-MOSFET for Q1 instead.

Comment: With 5V/500mA and 5V/5A, my MOSFET should dissipate 2.5W and 25W, is that right ? This is not for battery operated, but thanks for the note.

Comment: @Aurelien no.. YOu need to use the \$I^2 * R_{DS_{ON}}\$ equation for whatever MOSFET you chose at the gate voltage you have available.

Comment: So, to control the 5V/5A switch, I can use a FQP27P06 (page 2,
 here : [link](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2285784.pdf)). The dissipated power should be 0.07*5² = 1.75W. Is that right ? For the NPN, can I use something like a 2N2222, is that enough to drive the mosfet from a 3.3V/40mA output ?

Comment: @Aurelien 2n2222 is fine, but your mosfet choice needs to have a gate voltage of -10V to get  0.07R..

Comment: I computed with the maximum Rds rating. If I use it only for 5V purpose, the dissipated power will be even less, no ?

Comment: Ya but that is at -10V on the gate.. YOu should be looking at more like this one https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/ND/NDB6020P.pdf

Comment: "P-Channel Logic Level" That's sound great. Thanks a lot.