# Integrated circuit which acts as a switch

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, amperage, switching

I have the following problem.

[image: Circuit with lock, battery and raspberry pi.]

I have an electronic door lock with opens the door whenever it is feeded with 12v (tested and it works perfectly).

My main issue is that the signal for opening the door won't be a physical switch, but a raspberry pi which can send up to 3.3V and no more than 51mA.

My first idea was using a relay, but as the raspberry doesn't have much current, it wasn't able to give enough power to the coil.

My second option was using an LM393 I had by connecting the raspberry to the input supply, but it seems that whenever there is no input the voltage just passes through.

My last attempt was was trying to use a 2N2222 and it did not work.

Consider that all these attempts probably were failed due to my deplorable knowledge, they might be right but they were used on the wrong way.

What should I use for acting just like a switch?

Comment: Have you tried searching for "raspberry pi relay" ? I get 11.900.000 hits.

Comment: Use the built-in schematic editor to draw the circuit you used with the 2N2222 transistor, then explain exactly what happened when you tried to use this circuit. We also need a link to the datasheet for the lock itself.

Comment: companies make MOSFET Gate Drivers, with trip-points about 1.5 volts, and ability to drive 9 or even 12 amps (heatsinking may be needed).

Answer (score 1):

A circuit like this usually works well. The problem is you need current carrying capability, BJT's have a voltage drop and heat up with higher current. A mosfet could be used, like a Pmosfet which is voltage controlled, but the voltage needs to be able to reach the voltage of the mosfet. So you need a switch that works well below 3.3V (BJT) and a mosfet which has a low on resistance for current.

[image]
Source: [Part selection for high-side switch](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/342624/part-selection-for-high-side-switch)